# xlsm created with Excel 2010 - "Can't find project or library" on Excel 2016

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA macro which was working fine in Excel 2010. When I run it in Excel 2016 I get "Can't find project or library" on the line starting "nCashAdded = Application.InputBox":

```
Sub InsertNewHistory()
Dim nCashAddedInPeriod As Long

nCashAdded = Application.InputBox("Cash added in previous period:", "Cash In Period", Type:=1)
```

Here are the references that I have set:

[image: References]

Should I have any other references set?

Comment: Try to uncheck the last one that is marked as `MISSING:` and rerun your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For office 2010 the location for ATPVBAEN.XLAM was C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE14\Library\Analysis\

For Office 2016 (on windows 7) the location is now : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\Library\Analysis

Just uncheck the missing refernce, close the file, re-open and  browse to new location  and set reference.

You can also try to enable Analysis tool pack and it should make the addin available by default.

File--> Add-Ins -->  Excel Add-Ins , Click Go... and check Analysis ToolPak-VBA